# Permission denied in copying textfiles

Tags: python, shutil

I want to move a file to another folder, but my permissions seems to be denied.

I have tried googling the problem, and although this is probably a pretty simple problem, I am not able to find solutions. I am the administrator on the system.

```
import os
import shutil
import re
textregex = re.compile(r'(.*).txt')
folder_files = os.listdir('D:\\progetti python\\renamedates.py\\dates')
for filename in folder_files:
    txtfiles = textregex.findall(filename)
    print('found some text files: ' + filename)
    for file in txtfiles:
        shutil.copy(f'{file}','D:\\progettipython\\renamedates.py\\newfolder')
```

I expect to copy my file (which is a textfile) without having my copy denied.

Comment: correct that you have `D:\\progettipython\\renamedates.py\\newfolder` renamedates.py in folder path ? i mean its possible to name folder like this

Comment: `D:\\progetti python` and `D:\\progettipython` are different paths altogether. Was this your intention? Do both of these paths exist?

Comment: bad habit i had, didn't put the underscore. I'm going to check whether that was the error cause or not EDIT: that isn't the problem

Comment: is it  a windows environment?

Comment: yes, windows 10 pro

Comment: actually i think your path is wrong thats all otherwise it should work test with a simple path like i provided in my answer then check your path again

Answer (score 1):

I can give you an example how to copy just `.txt` from folder a to folder b:

using [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) to easy check for textfile ext.

```
import shutil
import glob

textfiles = glob.glob(r'C:\foldera\*.txt')
for filename in textfiles:
    shutil.copy(f'{filename}',r'C:\folderb')
```

Comment: @MicheleCeccacci no problem you can upvote and mark the answer as correct ^_°